# Does Azure DevOps supports xspec

Tags: xslt, azure-devops, xspec

We are using Azure DevOps for our repositories. Our code consist of XSLT's for its validation we have written XSpecs.
For CI/CD process we are planning to implement Pipelines rather than jenkins, but not able to get the information whether Azure DevOps supports xspecs to run on runtime. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Do you call xspec.sh or xspec.bat to run the test?

Comment: it is xspec.xsl

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Azure DevOps but I can read on [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-yaml?view=vsts) that you need to provide an `azure-pipelines.yml` file at the root of your repository. For writing this file you can take inspiration from the [AppVeyor yml file](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/blob/master/appveyor.yml) (AppVeyor is an online CI for Windows). The key part is when  [run-xspec-tests.cmd](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L96) is invoked, this allows to execute all the files with extension .xspec inside a test folder (you can find [the file run-xspec-tests.cmd here](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/blob/master/test/run-xspec-tests.cmd)). Also, make sure you install Saxon and the other dependencies in the yml file.

If you write an `azure-pipelines.yml`, I would be interested to add it to the [XSpec wiki documentation](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/wiki) on GitHub so that you can help other people who need to run XSpec in Azure DevOps (feel free to describe how you did it via an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/issues/new)).